# github non-fast-forward error

Tags: git, github

I'm fairly new to Git and I'm running into the following situation:

1. I am doing a course through my employer on Python. Basically you download a ZIP file which is a directory with files, exercises, etc. You modify the code in the exercises folder to get the right solutions.
2. Now I need to push these updated code files to a git repo.
3. But to do everything properly, I need to fork the original repo, to where I should push my updated code.
4. So I forked this repo, but did not clone it to my local machine, because if I did it would overwrite the updated code (right?)
5. I tried to do as follows.
6. Open Git, and navigate to the folder in my machine with the updated code
7. Then I ran the following code:

git init
git add .

```
git commit -m "Add corrections"
git remote add origin [the forked repo in company github]
git push
```

And then I receive the non-fast-forward error.

**My question is, how do I push the updated version of a repo file when that file is in my local without having to clone the directory and manually replace the files?**

Here is my `git status` log:

```
$ git status
rebase in progress; onto 8e66f31
You are currently rebasing branch 'master' on '8e66f31'.
  (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
  (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   SSH_KEY.txt
        new file:   data/baby_names.csv
        new file:   data/rc play.py
        new file:   exercises/compare.py
        new file:   exercises/stats.py

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both added:      data/NY.csv
        both added:      data/NY_sample.csv
        both added:      data/series_I.dat
        both added:      data/series_II.dat
        both added:      data/series_III.dat
        both added:      data/series_IV.dat
        both added:      exercises/classes_1.py
        both added:      exercises/classes_2.py
        both added:      exercises/exceptions.py
        both added:      exercises/streaming.py
        both added:      exercises/tests.py
        both added:      test_code
```

Answer (score -1):

One simple way is to clone your fork, copy your modified files on top of the clone with replacement, then do the usual `git add -A`, `git commit -m` and so forth.

Another way would be to commit your changes in your own directory, then add your fork as a remote to it, reset to latest from fork, then apply your commit on top.

In your own directory:

```
git init
git add -A
git commit -m <msg>   # <- note this commit id
git remote add origin <fork git address>
git reset --hard origin/master
git cherry-pick <commit id from third step>
```

You'll have to resolve conflicts if any, then you're good.

Comment: I get the first part, which is what I want to avoid because of I'm going to have to do this for several folders.

Unfortunately I don't follow the second part.

Comment: Down votes? At least add a comment why you don't think the answer is good. @vashts85: I expanded on the answer to make it clearer, but I don't see how doing this to several folders is related. You can write a script to repeat this.